# Add a PostGIS layer in a QGIS project as a table with no geometry

Tags: qgis, postgis

As a example, if I check the option *Also list tables with no geometry* on the *Add SpatiaLite layer(s)* dialog, it's possible to add to the project a table with a geometry column as a table with no geometry:

[image: Add SpatiaLite Layer dialog, listing tables with no geometry]

Is it possible to do the same thing with PostGIS? (I'm using QGIS 2.18.8)

[image: Add PostGIS Layer dialog, listing tables with no geometry]

Comment: I'm inclined to just answer 'Yes it is'. But likely you already tried it yourself and came up with a different conclusion? Was there a problem with it?

Comment: When I check 'Also list tables with no geometry', I don't find the duplicated tables, but with no geometry.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I don't think it is possible. What is your use case? In general, it shouldn't hurt to add the table as a geometry and then just disable it, you should still be able to do a join on it in QGIS.

Comment: In our DB schema, we have a PIPES table (linestring), a ADRESSES table (point) and a CONNECTIONS table (linestring). The CONNECTIONS table references the other two tables, and a trigger draws the shortest line between the point of the adress and the line of the pipe. We need to add the connection without manually draw the geometry.

Comment: And what stops you from doing it? afaik you should be able to edit this table on its reference fields. As a bonus you would right away see the geometry being updated.

Comment: When I want to add a new feature, how can I jump directly to the feature form without draw the geometry? I know I can draw anything and later the trigger will correct everything, but I'd like to make things simple to the users of the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61766/discussion-between-pahbloo-marks-and-tilt).